# .NET 6 C# Blazor Server app code behind file public property not in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

Created a code behind file in a .NET 6 Blazor app.

I have a public property that refuses to be recognized in the Razor page.

```
@page "/sessions"
@inject appData appdata

<h1>Sessions</h1>

<TelerikGrid Data="AllSessions"
             Pageable = "true"
             Sortable = "true">
    <GridColumns>
        <GridColumn Field="@nameof(SessionData.userID)" Width="45px" Title="User Name"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field="@nameof(SessionData.applicationName)" Width="185px" Title="App Name"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field="@nameof(SessionData.farmName)" Width="85px" Title="Site"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field="@nameof(SessionData.serverName)" Width="55px" Title="Server Name"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field="@nameof(SessionData.sessionkey)" Width="100px" Title="Session ID"></GridColumn>
    </GridColumns>
</TelerikGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
using ctxJLOBlazer.server.Data;
using ctxJLOBlazer.server.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace ctxJLOBlazer.server.Pages
{
    public partial class SessionsBase : ComponentBase
    {
        [Inject]
        public ICloudSessions CloudSessions { get; set; } = default!;

        [Inject]
        public IOnPremsessions OnPremsessions { get; set; } = default!;

        [Inject]
        public appData app { get; set; } = default!;

        public List<SessionData> cSessions { get; set; } = default!;
        public List<SessionData> premSessions { get; set; } = default!;
        public List<SessionData> AllSessions { get; set; } = new List<SessionData>();

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            cSessions = CloudSessions.getCloudSessions(app.userid).ToList();

            premSessions = OnPremsessions.GetOnPremSessons(app.userid).ToList();

            if (cSessions.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var cld in cSessions)
                {
                    AllSessions.Add(cld);
                }
            }

            if (premSessions.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var prem in premSessions)
                {
                    AllSessions.Add(prem);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `AllSessions` property keeps giving me not in current context.  What am I missing?

Comment: If you need further help, pls show the error pic, and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need register your Service method like `WeatherForecastService`,

[image]

I have test your code and create a simple SessionsService.